# Autolayout issue with constraintWithItem VS constraintsWithVisualFormat

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I have pretty simple UI that works well with constraintsWithVisualFormat, I tried to replace that with constraintWithItem and for some reason it is not working. I don't know what's wrong here.

The literal sentence I understood is

> Vertically, the contentView should fill the entire height of its
>   superview with no padding.

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(contentView);
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[contentView]|"
                                                               options:0
                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                 views:viewsDictionary];
[containerView addConstraints:constraints];


//Below is my alternative code NOT working, but this should work too?
NSLayoutConstraint *constraints =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:containerView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0];
[containerView addConstraint:constraints];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new code specifies the height, but not position. The visual format specification says nothing about the item’s height, but instead pins the top and bottom edges of the views to each other.

Instead of creating constraint for height, create two constraints, one for top margin, and one for bottom margin, pinning the edges of contentView to containerView.

Comment: I also have a horizontal constraint H:|[contentView]|, so that means I need left and right too? I think I have problem translating VFL

Comment: Yes, same applies to horizontal as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should change it from height to top. And also add similar constraint to bottom.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraints =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:containerView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0];
[containerView addConstraint:constraints];
```

Answer (score 0):

This visual format:

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(contentView);
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[contentView]|"
                                                               options:0
                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                 views:viewsDictionary];
[containerView addConstraints:constraints];
```

should be replaced with **two** constraints:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:containerView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0];
[containerView addConstraint: topConstraint];
```

**and**

```
NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:containerView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0];
[containerView addConstraint:bottomConstraint];
```

Comment: So the real question may be is what is the literal translation of V:|[contentView]| and H:|[contentView]|

Comment: `V:|[contentView]|` means "snap contentView to the top **and** to the bottom of its super view", `H:|[contentView]|` means "snap contentView to the leading **and** to the trailing of its superview." If you set 'NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeftToRight' as an option, leading and trailing are replaced left and right.

Comment: @AtifImran if you are really curious how visual format are translated, you can iterate over constraints array. This array contains NSLayoutConstraint objects, then you can print out its debugDescription.